# Java hashset contains duplicates

Tags: java

I have a hashset of Car objects eg `Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>`.

The Car class is briefly given below

```
public abstract class Car {
  protected Piece current;
  protected Piece;
  ....
  ....
  ....
  @Override
  public booleanll) return false;
      if ((obj.getClass() == this.getClass())) {
        Car o = (Carrent.equals(o.current) && other.equals(o.other)) || (current.equals) && other.et)));
      }
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((current == null) ? 0 : current.hashCode());
      result = prime =pokmob result;
  }
```

As you can see above, Car is an abstract class so I have two other classes `BigCar` and `SmallCar` extending the Car abstract class. And my set contains BigCar and SmallCar objects.
Also note that these subclasses do not override the equals and hashcode method.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: Without a [mcve], all we can say is that you've probably broken `equals` somewhere... but we can't tell with incomplete data.

Comment: @JonSkeet this is the complete data. i have only 2 fields in the car class. see equals method above

Comment: What's the code for `Piece.hashCode()`?

Comment: This is *far* from complete: 1) You've only provided an abstract class. We can't possibly create an instance of it. 2) You're using `Piece` but you haven't shown that class. 3) You're using `Reaction` but you haven't shown that class. 4) You haven't provided an example of constructing the equal values and adding them into the set. If you'd truly provided a [mcve], we'd be able to copy, paste, compile, run, and observe the problem. You're a long way from that right now.

Comment: `name == other.name && color == other.color`?  What is `name`?  What is `color`?  How likely is it two instances of the object have the exact same `name` and `color` **objects**?

Comment: @Joe *very likely* Really? How can we tell? And how do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

In your `hashCode` method, the two fields are not treated symmetrically - so two cars with `current` and `other` swapped will NOT have the same hashcode.

For example you could use this instead (also note the use of `Objects::hash` to avoid the null checks):

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
  return Objects.hash(current) * Objects.hash(other);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your `hashCode` `current` and `other` are not interchangeable.

Lets denote `current`'s value as `x` and `other`'s value as `y` for some instance.

The value of `hashCode` is `31*(31+x)+y`.

Now, for another instance, if `other` is `x` and `current` is `y` (which means that second instance should be equal to the first instance), `hashCode` is now `31*(31+y)+x` which is not equal to `31*(31+x)+y` for most values of `x` and `y`.

Hence you are breaking the contract of `hashCode`, since if `a.equals(b) == true`, `a.hashCode()` must be equal to `b.hashCode()`.

Comment: @Joe One that doesn't depend on the order of `current` and `other`. Examples are `other+current`, `other*current`, etc...